# Stderr redirection unexpectedly redirects some BASH built-ins as well

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to hide all the stderr from users running an interactive BASH script but keep the errors in a log file.
However, simple stderr redirection quite unexpectedly hides some BASH output as well that should go to *stdout* instead.
Have tried this on two systems and got the same results (one has **GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)** and the other is on MacOS X).

I have a lingering suspicion that it could be caused by the `exec` replacing the shell... but another built-in (`times`) works as expected and outputs to *stdout*!

An example:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 2>>file_log

echo This will be printed to stdout, as expected

ls ThereIsNoSuchFileOnEarth # this will go to “file_log”, as expected

read –p 'User would never see this prompt and it would go to file_log. Totally unexpected.' –r -e test

species=”Daleks Raxacoricofallapatorians Judoon”

select enemy in $species;
do
     # …code omitted as the user would never see the list. It would go into file_log again!
done
```

Comment: Note your code has "curly" quotes, not plain single/double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @glennjackman, that was just a typo (I was writing this code by hand here) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prompts from `read` and `select` *are supposed to* go to Standard Error, as they are prompts presumably for user interaction and not actual *output*.  This allows you to run `tool.sh > tool.out` and still use `read` and `select` to collect information from the user without "contaminating" the actual output.

Standard Output is meant to be the typical output of a program, ideally such that it could be piped into Standard Input of another with neither fuss, nor muss.

This is also why `curl`, for example, presents its download progress on Standard Error rather than Standard Output; you can `curl  http://www.example.com/path/to/file > file` and only the contents of `file` is displayed (and therefore redirected into `file`, while informational data are displayed using standard error.

Comment: For `select`, [it's explicitly documented to use `stderr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-select): _"The set of expanded words is printed on the standard error output stream,..."_. For `read`, I can't see it mentioned in the online documentation.

Comment: That's odd, my manual states, for `read -p` the following in relevant part:  `Display prompt on standard error...`  The `bash` manual, `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS` section, on `read`, under the `-p` option.

Comment: Ok good, the man page has it then. I can't see it here, though: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Comment: I wonder whether a pull request can be submitted for that bug (:

Comment: Thanks @DopeGhoti for a perfect answer! I knew it! It must have been an expected behaviour and not a bug :)

Comment: Always pleased to have helped!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `exec` to redirect stderr for the whole shell, this affects the whole shell.

You either cannot use `exec` to redirect the whole stderr, or you need to call something like:

```
read .... 2> /dev/tty
```

to have the builtins in question create readable output for stderr.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've been thinking abou this "workaround" as well but wanted to understand the reason behind the madness... Thanks for the answer (unfortunately I can't upvote due to low rep)!

Comment: Oh wait now I can :) Upvoted :)